Inconsistency while getting data from Ringba API
I am trying to get call logs data from Ringba platform using Ringba API. I use the following script to get the data in specific date range.
function fetchRecordingData(spreadsheet, specificBuyerName, reportStart, reportEnd) {

  var url = "https://api.ringba.com/v2/{{account id}}/calllogs";
  const apiToken = '###';

  var extractedData = [];
  var offset = 0;
  var size = 1000;

  while (true) {
    var payload = {
      "reportStart": reportStart, 
      "reportEnd": reportEnd,    
      "orderByColumns": [],
      "filters": [],
      "formatDateTime": true,
      "formatPercentages": true,
      "formatTimeZone": "America/Denver",
      "formatTimespans": true,
      "offset": offset,
      "size": size,
      "valueColumns": [
        { "column": "callDt" },
        { "column": "campaignName" },
        { "column": "publisherName" },
        { "column": "inboundPhoneNumber" },
        { "column": "buyer" }
      ]
    };

    var options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Token " + apiToken,
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
      },
      "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    var records = jsonResponse.report.records;
    if (!records || records.length === 0) {
      break;
    }
 
    var filteredData = records.filter(function(record) {
      return record.buyer && record.buyer.toLowerCase().trim() === specificBuyerName.toLowerCase().trim();
    }).map(function(record) {
      return [
        record.callDt,
        record.campaignName,
        record.buyer,
        record.publisherName,
        record.inboundPhoneNumber
      ];
    });

    extractedData = extractedData.concat(filteredData);

    if (records.length < size) {
      break;
    }

    offset += size;
  }

    console.log(extractedData.length) 
 }

There are total of 831 records for that given date, when I run randomly it gives the correct number of records. However, when I run it 2-3 times in quick succession, the number of records in output keeps changing (825,837).
Then I wait for 5-10 minutes, run it, and it gives the correct output (831) again. I am unclear why doesn't it always give the same output. Any guidance to point out my mistake would be much appreciated.

The question title needs to summarize the question adequately. Also, the code doesn't look to be [mcve] as there are missing details like how the function is called, the relevant spreadsheet details and how the function is run " 2-3 times in quick succession" .

there is no detail about spreadsheet, it is just used to store values, I agree with your code comment, quick succession means running the script manually 2,3 times in a minute or so

If you have already found that running the function in quick succession causes problems, you should avoid that.

Disable the UI element used to call the function to avoid quick successions due to user-on keyboard behavior like double clicking.

Add Utilities.sleep(milliseconds) to force a wait time before executing the HTTP-POST request. You might use the Properties Service to store a timestamp and if-statement using the elapsed time since the last execution to run Utilities.sleep(milliseconds) only when necessary to avoid the problem.

Use the Google Apps Script Lock Service to avoid multiple HTTP-POST requests simultaneously. This might happen because the execution times might vary. This implies that the earlier execution might have a delay or take more time to finish, causing the simultaneous executions.



I found a solution. In the Payload the filter parameters need to be specified to get consistent data every time the script runs. So it works fine when I changed this:
var payload = {
      "reportStart": reportStart,  
      "reportEnd": reportEnd,   
      "orderByColumns": [],
      "filters": [],
      "formatDateTime": true,
      "formatPercentages": true,
      "formatTimeZone": "America/Denver",
      "formatTimespans": true,
      "offset": offset,
      "size": size,
      "valueColumns": [
        { "column": "callDt" },
        { "column": "campaignName" },
        { "column": "publisherName" },
        { "column": "inboundPhoneNumber" },
        { "column": "buyer" }
      ]
    };

To this:
  var payload = {
      "reportStart": reportStart,
      "reportEnd": reportEnd,
      "orderByColumns": [],
      "filters": [
       {
      "anyConditionToMatch": [
        {
          "column": "buyer",
          "value": specificBuyerName,
          "isNegativeMatch": false,
          "comparisonType": "EQUALS"
        }]
       }],
      "formatDateTime": true,
      "formatPercentages": true,
      "formatTimeZone": "America/Denver",
      "formatTimespans": true,
      "offset": offset,
      "size": size,
      "valueColumns": [
        { "column": "callDt" },
        { "column": "campaignName" },
        { "column": "publisherName" },
        { "column": "inboundPhoneNumber" },
        { "column": "buyer" }
      ]
    };

